# Typed ref cells?

Tags: types, ocaml, union, dereference, ref

I'm an ocaml noob.  Using plain old ref to int, or other simple built-in types, so far works for me as expected in all ways. I've used them in the context of tuples where the refs are members of tuples. I can update the refs, dereference them, etc.

```
 # let e = 1, ref 1;;
 val e : int * int ref = (1, {contents = 1})
 # snd e := 2;;
 - : unit = ()
 # e;;
 - : int * int ref = (1, {contents = 2})
 # !(snd e);;
 - : int = 2
```

But as soon as I declare a named type "of ref" to some other aggregate (or even built-in simple) type, things go badly in general. I find I cannot alter the references anymore unlike before when they were not declared as types "of ref" to something. The ! and := operators fail.

And the semantics appear to change in weird apparently inconsistent ways. Below is just one example. Why is it legal to write the first code block below but it appears to be illegal to do something similar at the top loop (further below)?  The first block is accepted by the compiler, and wherein we can match against a ref that is a constructed type and access its value using the ! operator on lines 13 and 14. This is all within the context of a circular queue and loaded from a file in the top loop using #use:

```
type 'a element = 'a * 'a pointer 
and 'a pointer = Pointer of 'a element ref;;
let next (_,n) = n;;
type 'a queue = 'a element option ref;;

let create () = None;;
(*passes compiler and behaves well*)
let enqueue queue x = 
  match !queue with
      None ->
    let rec elem = (x, Pointer (ref elem)) in 
    queue := Some elem;
    | Some (_, Pointer last_newest_next) -> (*Insert between newest and oldest*)
      let oldest = !last_newest_next in
      let elem = (x, Pointer (ref oldest)) in
      last_newest_next := elem;
      queue := Some elem;;
```

At the top loop similar efforts (and variations upon this) fail, as below, where I also decompose a tuple using a function and then try to invoke the same operator:

```
let rec elem = (1, Pointer (ref elem));;
let last = !(next elem);;
Characters 12-22:
let last = !(next elem);;
          ^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type int pointer
   but an expression was expected of type 'a ref
```

Yes, I am using -rectypes but I wanted to try this out for once without using a recursive abbreviated type and I've been stuck on it every since. Note the following works at the top loop, but I'm not certain it is equivalent and what I really want:

```
let last = next elem;;
val last : int pointer = (* ...  *)
```

And if the first code block is changed on line 14 to not use the ! operator, it breaks. A rewrite (as below) causes the enqueue function to pass the compiler but to misbehave:

```
 (*compiles but fails - que only ever holds one item*)
let enqueue queue x = 
  match !queue with
      None ->
    let rec elem = (x, Pointer (ref elem)) in 
    queue := Some elem;
    | Some (_, Pointer last_newest_next) ->
      let oldest = last_newest_next in
      let elem = (x, Pointer oldest) in
      last_newest_next := elem;
      queue := Some elem;;
```

It must be that without the ! operator (and with a few other changes), the second to last line is actually making a pointer in elem point to itself instead of updating a different pointer (from within the decomposed element of the match) to point to elem as originally intended. Regardless, I still don't see why the semantics appear to be inconsistent between a top loop tuple decomposition of a typed ref and doing the same from an ml file...if that's even the cause of all this. Or is decomposition from a pattern match somehow not the same as decomposing a tuple via a function?!?

And I used a dequeue function to test the behavior of the above functions:

```
let dequeue queue = 
  match !queue with
      None -> raise Not_found
    | Some (_, Pointer oldest_ref) ->
      let oldest = !oldest_ref in
      let (x, Pointer next_ref) = oldest in
      let next = !next_ref in
      if next == oldest then
    queue := None
      else 
    oldest_ref := next;
      x;;
```

I can appreciate why I might want to shun ref cells in a functional language but I need to know how to use them when it is imperative (no pun intended).

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult for me to find a particular question in what you write. However, OCaml is not inconsistent or illogical. This is one of the beauties of "modern" FP languages--their type systems are based on sound mathematics. For now I'll focus on the first thing you show that doesn't work:

```
# let rec elem = (1, Pointer (ref elem));;
# let last = !(next elem);; ## TYPE ERROR HERE
```

It seems like the problem is pretty clear if you just look at what `next elem` is. As you can see from your definition of `elem`, `next elem` is `Pointer (ref elem)`. This isn't a reference. Its constructor is `Pointer`. So it makes no sense to apply the `!` operator to it, which is what the type error is telling you. If you want to get `elem` back out of `next elem`, you need to destructure the `Pointer` constructor.

```
# let unpointer (Pointer x) = x;;
# let last = !(unpointer (next elem));;
# last == elem;;
- : bool = true
#
```

**Edit:** For what it's worth, your circular list type looks a bit convoluted to me. If you really need circular lists, you might look at the doubly-linked list implementation that appears in OCaml Batteries Included: [BatDllist](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batDllist.ml). It's a straightforward low-level implementation that looks a lot like what you would write in C. Even better would be to use built-in OCaml lists! I've never felt a need to use circular lists in many years of OCaml coding (just one data point).

Comment: Apologies for the convoluted question; thanks to all for all the answers as they helped my understanding immensely.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have an extremely low-level understanding of the semantics of programming language. In this case insisting to think low has seemingly led you astray. The semantics of references in OCaml is consistent, and everything strange you observe here is due to mistakes on your part, not the language semantics.

If that can help you, here is a way to describe OCaml's semantics to someone that thinks at low implementation levels. It's not how I would usually describe it to beginners, but if you insist on thinking in terms of pointers, aggregates, and pointers:

- values in OCaml are either representable by integers and immutable, and passed as is, or a pointer to some heap block; mutability is simpler to reason about in this setting that in a language that would make by value/by reference distinctions, everything is shared unless explicitly deconstructed or reconstructed
- references are derived concepts defined as a record with a mutable field, `type 'a ref = {mutable contents: 'a};`, this corresponds to a simple box that points to a value and can change the value it points to; it is polymorphic and behave in a consistent way. In particular, any typing error you observe is due to an error in your code, look harder!
- the type `type foo = Foo of t` is distinct from `t`; you can convert a `v : t` into a `foo` with `Foo v`, and a `v : foo` into a `t` with `(match v with (Foo x) -> x)`.

I think you're mixing too many difficulties at the same time. Drop `-rectypes` and have you code working, and then you can consider adding it back to see if it can lighten the code. The reason why `-rectypes` isn't enabled by default is that some code that is certainly an error (`let sum x = x (* + *) x`) is accepted, only to result in a cryptic error message when using it later. If you are uncomfortable with other aspects of the language you don't want that to happen.

Comment: It would be even easier to reason if you pretend that all types are pointers to some heap block. It doesn't make a difference for integers because you would consider them to be immutable, in the same way as for float.

Comment: Indeed, but I don't want to create worries that "this is horribly inefficient", hence my distinctions. If you have suggestions, I would be interested in a way to describe the extreme sharing in a more abstract way that invoking pointers and stuff.